# What kind of connector is this?

Tags: power, connector

I'm trying to identify this connector.  I suspect it is some kind of Molex connector, but I can't figure out which one.

Here are two pictures I've taken.

[image: Image 1]

[image]

Currently it is attached to a [Micro-USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Micro_connectors) plug at the other end, but I want to switch it to a new lightning connector.

What is it? What kind of crimping tool would I need to make this work?

Comment: You do know that the lightning connectors have a security chip embedded in them, right? If you're trying to use this to charge your iDevice, it won't work unless iOS believes your security chip is legit!

Comment: Yes, I do, but I think it is in the 9pin end.  So if I buy one, and cut off the USB end, I should be OK. As long as I can track down this connector!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "guessing-game" type question. See meta.superuser.com/a/6074/23133

Answer (score 1):

Try the [KK family](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=..) Molex. It looks about right to me.

The 4-pin [IDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector) also comes up in my searching, but I think that's a connector type rather than a product per se.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  My connector only has 4 wires, the KK family looks to have 6.

Comment: ah. that figures with the results i was getting for IDC. Nice to know, thanks ! Kin dof bugging me because i've seen these connectors used also, but i can't remember where it was I saw it to look it up.

Comment: "4 pin SMD" also looks pretty likely. http://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=307

Comment: The link is broken (404). Possible alternative: https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/kk-connectors