# What interface do I need for my graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, pci, bus, minipci

The motherboard died on a gaming laptop belonging to a friend of mine, and I am rebuilding it as a desktop as a favor for him.

According to the specs from alienware's website and several reviews online, the graphics cards are two AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870 GPUs in a crossfire configuration.

When I pulled the GPUs, I was a little confused; the interface was clearly not a standard PCIe interface, about 3 1/4" wide with a single space between pins roughly in the middle of the pins (whereas the PCI cards I've dealt with have had their gap significantly to one side). I did some research on legacy ports and newer PCI interfaces, but nothing Looks right from what I've seen.

In selecting a motherboard I obviously should be looking for one with crossfire support, but what interface do I need for the cards?

Here is a picture of a card with the same interface:

[image: http://www.amd.com/PublishingImages/Public/Photograph_ProductShots/HighResolutionJPEG/47948A_AMD_AMR_HD5700_HD5600_MXMBoard_Flat.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're faced with an [MXM module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module), which is kinda sort of the standard for replaceable laptop graphics cards. There are adaptors between MXM III and PCIe but they seem expensive enough that buying a new GPU looks like a better option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. MXM Does appear to be correct bus. The GPUs, although several years old, were top-of-the-line when they came out, so it may make sense to spend $100+ on an adapter (I'd have to look at some benchmarks to be sure). However, I cant find a single vendor of used or new MXM adapters. If you know of any I would be very grateful for a link, otherwise thank you again for your help!

Comment: Didn't have much luck there, outside that 'they exist'.