# What kind of power port is this?

Tags: power-supply

I'm planning on getting a new PSU and I was shopping online when I saw this thing.

[image: PSU NZXT HALE90 850W]

What kind of port is this? I've never seen it before, and I definitely can't find cables for this.

For reference, this is a "normal" 3 prong cable:

[image: Black power cord]

The PSU itself is a NZXT HALE90 850W.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything strange about it.  Look like your typical 3-prong power connector.

Comment: The prongs are side to side instead of up and down, that's odd.

Comment: It's like they avoided a long-time standard for no reason (expect maybe to sell you cables). I'd avoid that PSU like the plague.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The thing is, I see no spare cords for sale at their site. This is confusing me.

Comment: Looks proprietary...why? I don't have any idea...

Comment: Its just a standard 16amp IEC-C19 connector.  There are tons of them on Amazon.

Comment: That's bizarre, I've built and used plenty of Servers, UPS and such in my life and I've NEVER seen that coupler.  Anyhow, it's _A_ standard at least, so you can get them. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've settled for a nice Rosewill one, this just looked weird, and I had no idea where it came from.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There are boxes of C19/C20 at my job. Old Mac G5s use them too since they're rated 10A and that's the limit for C13/C14.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 pretty sure i've used apc ups units that use those connections. That was in europe. Quite common i thought until i saw this question.

Comment: I have seen these plugs many times in datacenters - on the servers and on the rack Power Distribution Units, but never on a consumer machine before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I identify hardware I am unfamiliar with on my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It would appear that is a [IEC 320 C19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C19.2FC20_coupler) coupler.

[image]

> This coupler is used for some IT applications where higher currents are required, as for instance, on high-power workstations and servers, uninterruptible power supplies, power distribution units, large network routers, switches, blade enclosures, and similar equipment.

For North America you could use a NEMA 5-15P to IEC 320 C19 cable [like this one](http://ca.startech.com/Cables/Computer-Power/External/8foot-Computer-Power-Cord-NEMA-5-15P-to-IEC-320-C19~PXT515C198) (for example).

Comment: The significant difference is that the C19 is rated for 16 amps and the more familiar C14 is rated for 10 amps.  This kind of prong configuration change to indicate current capacity is very common in 220V NEMA plugs.

Comment: In addition, the NEMA 5-15 plug is only rated for 15 amps.  Mostly not a problem since most C19 devices will draw less than that, but you may need a C19 to NEMA 5-20 for something like a 1500W PSU.

Answer (score 0):

One of many "Don't plug your random stuff in my socket" plugs

UK ref, the Walsall plug, right vs Standard UK 13A, left. -

[image]

Comment: Wrong end dude.

Comment: Also wrong orientation.

Comment: was just an example - & I couldn't find good pics of the sockets, much easier to see on the plugs.