# What is this cable connector?

Tags: cable

Somewhere I've found a cable looking as this:

[image: IUnknown cable connector]

Its opposite end looks exactly the same.

The cable is thick, so I think it supports also strong current. In the IT, similar cables are belonging mostly to printers, so I assume it can be maybe some like a printer cable, but what type of it is this?

Comment: @Mokubai If this question is _not_ about hardware, what is about hardware then? Please specify the exact location in the help center which closes this question out!

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not?lq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer

Comment: @peterh It's either a guessing game question or not about ***computer*** hardware. It's a SCART cable, typically used to connect old video players to TVs and absolutely nothing to do with computers.  This is another reason why "what's this connector used for?" is a bad type of question, you can hold up any connector that's never been seen on or even *near* a computer and claim to be on topic.

Comment: @KevinPanko These are meta posts, and isn't a part of the help center. The question was closed with a reasoning citing th help center. I conclude, the reasoning about the close of this question was not true.

Comment: @Mokubai It is also for you. You cited the help center, while closed the question, without a vote, as a single person decision. After asking the exact location in the help center I didn't get anything only a link to a meta post.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't unconditionally disagree if such questions wouldn't be allowed. I also see that the googlers of the future probably won't profit too many from it. What I disagree: closing the question citing the help center, while it isn't mentioned in the help center, only in many year old meta posts.

Comment: The help centre specifically states "If you have a question about … **computer** hardware, **computer** software ...  [And] not about …electronic devices" (e.g. TVs VCRs or media players). Which I feel is quite clear. Your question isn't about any kind of computer cable or even a connector you saw **on** a computer, it's about some random cable you *found*. I could show you several hundred photos of random connectors never seen in a computer, none of them would be on topic. Would you want us to play "identify this programmer" on [so]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scart lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART). Used to be commonly used for AV applications - eg between a VCR and TV.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fortunately, your answer was faster, as the hand of the mod... and finally I got my answer.