# View PC graphics output without monitor

Tags: windows-7, usb, display, external-display

I recently inherited an older PC running win7 and I wanted to see if it still works, the issue is I don't have an VGA monitor and VGA is all the computer supports, so at the moment, there is no way for me to see what is going on at the moment, so I was wondering if there is any software available that I can use on my android phone as a monitor via USB where I do not need to install any additional software on the older device. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I might be able to view the device's output, that would be brilliant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the answer is “no” – unless you already have the necessary software installed on the PC. A Virtual Network Controller (VNC) would be ideal, and do exactly what you want, as would TeamViewer, but if it Is not already installed on the PC, I don’t see how you can do it without a display. Perhaps you can find an old, very cheap RGB monitor on eBay, CraigList, the “for free” listing in your local newspaper? Maybe there’s one lying in a cupboard somewhere at work? Perhaps a PC repair shop could help? ... ->

Comment: ... Finally, is the PC really worth the effort, plus the cost of the RGB monitor you will have to buy (personally, I would put Linux on it & use it only for surfing the web, maybe email)?  Hmmm, perhaps you could ask at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if there is a cheap adapter available?

Comment: Yeah, It came with an older laptop as well, so i'd put linux on both of them and use them as a stack, but at the moment, this one has no way for me to see what I'm doing, assuming it still works at all.

Comment: But, buying a cheap RGB monitor can always come in handy as I've learnt multiple times! and still haven't bought a monitor...

Comment: When you power it on, do you see a power light? Do you hear a hard drive spin? If not, probably don't bother. If so, it's no guarantee, but maybe worth investigating?

Comment: The computer turns on, I hear the HDD and the fan and lights flash, so I assume it's not entirely broken.

Comment: If it really is RGB and you have a TV with SCART try using an RGB to Scart adapter.

Comment: @Antony - The author could just use any old monitor that supports VGA.  I assume the PC, supports VGA, RGA monitors would have supported it.  We are talking about a Windows 7 machine.  I am guessing the author is asking about VGA anyways.

Comment: As it turns out, the port is indeed a VGA. The original owner had said the machine was nearly 10 years old.

Comment: Maxivista, iDisplay, TwoUSB and similar software let you do what you are asking, but you have to set them up beforehand, so you won't be able to use them in this situation.

Comment: Jacob, when you answer a question from someone helping, the Comments pile up and up until they scroll off the screen. Instead, please click on [edit]  and expand your original post so you answer their question in the original post for all to see. When done, pls delete your Comments by clicking on the grey (x).

Comment: Understood, I will take your advice on board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's VGA, not RGB - you'll need some flavour of software for remote access. You can't just plug a phone into a PC over USB and get it to do *anything*, let alone be a monitor by itself.

Now the solution you *need* is something that converts VGA to a HDMI or DP - these are commodity items with a bunch of options. You can then plug it into a modern monitor. Presumably you can then set up some remote access software to run it over wifi.

Comment: I have a USB keyboard and mouse, controlling it is not the issue, but I did consider an adapter-like device.

Comment: RGB monitors do exist.  However, their input was VGA, so this is a problem that can be solved with the right adapter.  Any monitor that supports VGA will work, depending on the connectors, your question makes no mention of the connector the computer uses.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not too great with the different port types...

Comment: VGA basically does RGB analog signals and a bit more. Bit of a shameless plug but this is a [super useful post](https://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer) on hardware ID